# add plugins in blazor webassembly : how to manage dependency injection?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I currently load dynamic plugins in my webassembly with a HttpClient, it's ok it works.
But now, I want to register some of types in theses plugins in the mechanism of dependency injection.

How to manage that because registring of dependency injection is at application starting, before the load of the plugins...

Thank you

Comment: You can do it before the DI container has been built.